# How to make two JSF selectOneMenus that depend on each other with AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, selectonemenu

I have two selectOneMenu. I need following:

1. On first menu change I need to populate second one and some form's fields with AJAX
2. On second menu change I need to populate only some form's fields wit AJAX.

Populating second menu and form's fields on step 1 is perfect and right after first menu change, but there is a problem with populating form on step 2.
Nothing happens when I change second menu's value. But when I returned second menu value to NoSelectionOption ajax listener invoked. It seems that AJAX listener ignores values that was added with AJAX.

Here's my code fragments:

JSF:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Получатель:" />
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{paymentOrder.curContractor}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Выберите контрагента .." noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{paymentOrder.userContractors}" var="contr"
                        itemValue="#{contr.idcontractor}"
                        itemLabel="#{contr.pnamecontractor}"/>
                    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{paymentOrder.valueContractorChanged}" render="idINNContractor, idKPPContractor, idNameContractor, idContractorAccounts" execute="@this"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                    <h:outputText value="ИНН"/>
                    <h:inputText id="idINNContractor" value="#{paymentOrder.chosenContractor.inncontractor}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="КПП"/>
                    <h:inputText id="idKPPContractor"  value="#{paymentOrder.chosenContractor.kppcontractor}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Получатель"/>
                    <h:inputTextarea id="idNameContractor" value="#{paymentOrder.chosenContractor.pnamecontractor}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Счёт получателя:"/>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="idContractorAccounts" value="#{paymentOrder.curContractorAccount}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Выберите счёт .."  noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems  value="#{paymentOrder.contractorAccounts}" var="acc"
                            itemValue="#{acc.naccountcontractor}"
                            itemLabel="#{acc.advName}"/>
                        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{paymentOrder.valueAccountChanged}" render="idContrAcc, idNameContrBank, idBikContrBank, idAccContrBank" execute="@this"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Сч.№"/>
                    <h:inputText id="idContrAcc" value="#{paymentOrder.curContractorAccount}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>      
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:panelGrid columns="4">   
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Банк получателя"/>
                <h:inputTextarea id="idNameContrBank" value="#{paymentOrder.chosenBank.namebank}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="БИК"/>
                <h:inputText id="idBikContrBank" value="#{paymentOrder.chosenBank.bikbank}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Сч.№"/>
                <h:inputText id="idAccContrBank" value="#{paymentOrder.chosenBank.bankkorshet}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And my back bean fragment:

```
public class PaymentOrder {

    @EJB(lookup="JpaBankBean/local")
    private JpaBankBeanLocal jpaBean;
    private Paymentdocument pDocument;
    private Paymentorder pOrder;
    private Klbankrf chosenBank;

    private String curContractorAccount;
    private String curContractorBank;
    private String curContractor;
    private String err;
    private String chosenAccount;

    private Contractor chosenContractor;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Set contractorAccounts;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private List contractorBanks;
    private String userName;
    private Date nowDate;
    public PaymentOrder() {
        this.nowDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
              setUserName(((UserDetails)principal).getUsername());
            } else {
              setUserName(principal.toString());
            }   
        pDocument = new Paymentdocument();
        pOrder = new Paymentorder();
        chosenContractor = new Contractor();
        chosenBank = new Klbankrf();
    }
    public void valueContractorChanged()
    {
        chosenContractor = jpaBean.getContractor(Integer.valueOf(getCurContractor()));
        setContractorAccounts(jpaBean.getContractorAccounts(Integer.valueOf(getCurContractor())));
        pDocument.setReceiver(chosenContractor.getPnamecontractor());
    }
    public List getUserContractors()
    {
        return jpaBean.getUserContractors(userName);
    }
    public void valueAccountChanged()
    {
        chosenBank.setNamebank("SBER");

        //TODO chosenBank = jpaBean.getContractorBank(getCurContractorAccount());
        //TODO setChosenAccount("012345678901234567890");
    }
}
```

So, "SBER" appear in idNameContrBank field only if I change second menu value to somethig and then change back to NoSelectOption. It is strange to me. 
I use RichFaces 4, JBoss AS 6.

I've found some information at this [forum](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2824), but there is no solution.
How to make second menu to change something? Or is there my mistake? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

I've made some experiments.
When I change second menu to some value populated with AJAX, page gets response like that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
    <changes>
        <update id="docForm:idContrAcc">
            <![CDATA[<input id="docForm:idContrAcc" type="text" name="docForm:idContrAcc" style=" width : 100%;" />]]>
        </update>
        <update id="docForm:idNameContrBank">
            <![CDATA[<textarea id="docForm:idNameContrBank" name="docForm:idNameContrBank" style=" width : 130px;"></textarea>]]>
        </update>
        <update id="docForm:idBikContrBank">
            <![CDATA[<input id="docForm:idBikContrBank" type="text" name="docForm:idBikContrBank" style=" width : 140px;" />]]>
        </update>
        <update id="docForm:idAccContrBank">
            <![CDATA[<input id="docForm:idAccContrBank" type="text" name="docForm:idAccContrBank" style=" width : 140px;" />]]>
        </update>
        <update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[3312710224811729695:3995303008700914422]]>
        </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

There are no values, but right IDs! How it can be? Why?

But if I return NoSelectionOption active then page gets response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
    <changes>
        <update id="docForm:idContrAcc">
            <![CDATA[<input id="docForm:idContrAcc" type="text" name="docForm:idContrAcc" value="" style=" width : 100%;" />]]>
        </update>
        <update id="docForm:idNameContrBank">
            <![CDATA[<textarea id="docForm:idNameContrBank" name="docForm:idNameContrBank" style=" width : 130px;">SBER</textarea>]]>
        </update>
        <update id="docForm:idBikContrBank">
            <![CDATA[<input id="docForm:idBikContrBank" type="text" name="docForm:idBikContrBank" style=" width : 140px;" />]]>
        </update>
        <update id="docForm:idAccContrBank">
            <![CDATA[<input id="docForm:idAccContrBank" type="text" name="docForm:idAccContrBank" style=" width : 140px;" />]]>
        </update>
        <update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
            <![CDATA[3312710224811729695:3995303008700914422]]>
        </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

It's seems OK - values are presented! But why does it happen when NoSelectionOption is active?!

Comment: Wait a minute... are you using PrimeFaces? No wonder I've never heard of `<a4j:ajax />`. You tagged your question with 'richfaces' which is a different library.

Comment: Oh, and as a side note, if you're using a generic type but don't want to specify the generics you can use something like: `Set<?>` and `List<?>` instead of having to use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`.

Comment: I use RichFaces 4. And thank you for side note :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect JSF might be overwriting your attempts since it usually calls all the setters for all the properties exposed on the page and it normally does this after the `valueChangeListener`s are executed. I've never seen the `<a4j:ajax />` tag but you could try the [`<a4j:support />`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/support.jsf?c=support&tab=usage) tag. Instead of this:

```
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{paymentOrder.valueContractorChanged}" render="idINNContractor, idKPPContractor, idNameContractor, idContractorAccounts" execute="@this"/>
```

Try this:

```
<a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="idINNContractor, idKPPContractor, idNameContractor, idContractorAccounts"/>
```

Since `ajaxSingle="true"` is included in the tag it means that only the setter for `curContractor` will be called (and not all the rest on the page like JSF normally does). Then you can call `valueContractorChanged` from the setter (or even just make it part of the setter).

If you replace all of the `<a4j:ajax />` tags in this way you should get the desired result. Check out more info about the tag via the link above.

Comment: Thanks, but <a4j:support> uses in RichFaces 3, and I use RichFaces 4 and it doesn't have <a4j:support> anymore.

Comment: I see, you're using the JSF 2.0 built-in AJAX tag? Sorry, I haven't had any experience with that one.